# Regex pattern for following example test test123

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex pattern for following example test test123 .first string between A-za-z and second string should be A-Za-z0-9

examples:
 hello world123 (true)
123 hello123 (false)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like **^[a-zA-Z]+[ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+$**

```js
function CheckValidation() {
    var str = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
    var pattern = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+[ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var res = pattern.test(str);
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtInput" />
<button onclick="CheckValidation()">Check</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the below and working fine

var pattern = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var res = pattern.test(str);

Comment: Why did you copy previous answer?